# Is there an emerging solution being provided integrating TypeScript with NPM modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'd like to build a node application using TypeScript.

From my research DefinitelyTyped is the 'standard' (by standard i mean most results from my google searching) way to access npm modules in my TypeScript application.

Are the TypeScript/NodeJS/NPM working towards each other, or are there other ways of building a TypeScript project using npm modules.

The current ways to get them to work together seem forced, but they seem like a natural fit.

Thanks

Comment: Check Angular 2: https://angular.io/

Comment: Yeah, typescript 2 has @types, read about it here: [The Future of Declaration Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)